# Best way to use state data after updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have updated my app to use `useReducer`, but have run into the problem with running code after updating state, that is [described here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer#ive-dispatched-an-action-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-state-value)

The solution it says is to pull the 'nextState' out by calling the reducer a second time manually, to calculate the new state, and then use that. But that seems a lengthy way of doing it, especially when I need to pass it to multiple functions. So before when I was using `this.state` in a class, I could just do:

```
this.setState(.....)
this.saveData()
this.somethingElse()
```

I now have to do something like:

```
dispatch({type: updateData, data: 'newdata'})

const action = {type: 'updateData', data: 'newdata'}
const nextState = reducer(state, action)
const { somekey } = nextState
saveData(nextState)
somethingElse(somekey)
```

Which just feels like there should be a slicker way of doing it. Is there? I suppose I could use a `useEffect` to monitor state for changes maybe? But then I would have to impose some limits to make sure it doesn't save when it has just loaded something, if that makes sense?

What better ways (if any) are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid having to add complex conditions to the `useEffect` would be to create an action to indicate that the data is pending to be saved.

```js
const handleNewData = useCallback(() => {
  dispatch({ type: 'updateData', data: 'newdata' });
  dispatch({ type: 'setDataAsPendingToSave', payload: true });
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (state.dataPendingToSave) {
    const { somekey } = state;
    saveData(state);
    somethingElse(somekey);
    dispatch({ type: 'setDataAsPendingToSave', payload: false });
  }
}, [state]);
```

Comment: I did think about this, but it feels like there should be a way of doing it that doesn't require this. Almost like an async/await...